# My jquery animation works in FF but not IE or Chrome

Tags: jquery, animation, cross-browser

I want a 'tab' sticking out on the right of the page, that slides in (from the right) on click. (and slides out again on 2nd click).
My code works in Firefox fine, but in IE and chrome it initially appears in the correct place, but on click - immediately swops to the left of the page.

Can someone guide/help me please to get it to work cross browser - thanks.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head> 

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="slider" style="position:fixed;width:340px;right:-300px;bottom:80px;z-index:999">
    <div id="slideButton"  style="position:relative;float:left;height:120px;width:40px;background:fuchsia;text-align:center;">S<br/>l<br/>i<br/>d<br/>e<br/>r<br/></div>
    <div id="slideContent" style="position:relative;float:left;height:120px;width:300px;background:yellow;">
    Slider text goes here <br/>(should slide in/out <br/>from right of page)    </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#slideButton').toggle(function() {
    $('#slider').animate({
        left: '-=200'
        }, 1500, 'swing', function() {
        // Animation complete. CALLBACK?
    });
}, function() {
    $('#slider').animate({
        left: '+=200'
        }, 1000, 'swing', function() {
        // Animation complete. CALLBACK?
    });
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're animating the css `left` property, i think you meant to animate the `right` instead. Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NpGMh/6/)

Answer (score 1):

replace left with right and swap += and -=

```
$('#slideButton').toggle(function() {
    $('#slider').animate({
        right: '+=200'
        }, 1500, 'swing', function() {
        // Animation complete. CALLBACK?
    });
}, function() {
    $('#slider').animate({
        right: '-=200'
        }, 1000, 'swing', function() {
        // Animation complete. CALLBACK?
    });
```

works for me in Chrome

Comment: Well a BIG thank you @Interstellar_Coder
.  With your change I have it working in all browser, but why it worked in FF before ... who cares .. it works now ;-)  - thanks.